# How to create a palindrome off a string that is INSIDE of an array

Tags: java

I am supposed to change every element of an array arr to be a palindrome.

I've tried making a for loop to make a new array, and made another for loop to make a palindrome off of the elements of the array, but apparently it doesn't really work out.

```
  public static String [] changeArrayToPalindrome(String [] arr){
  int length =arr.length;
  String[]newarray= new String[length];
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
     String a=arr[i];
     int n=a.length();
     if(a==null){
        System.out.println("null");
     }
     else if(a.equals("")){

      System.out.println("");
        }


     String newString="";
     for(int j=0; j<=n/2-1; j++){        

        newString+=a.charAt(j);
        newString+=a.charAt(n/2+j);

        newarray[j]=newString;
     }

  }
  return newarray;
   }
```

The tester is

```
String [] array={"street", null, "break", "oha", "", "pit", null,"atOyotA"};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(changeArrayToPalindrome(array)));
```

Supposed to print out

```
  //[street, null, break, oha, , pit, null, atOyotA]
  //[strrts, null, brerb, oho, , pip, null, atOyOta]
```

I know I'm not supposed to put System.out.println for the null or the empty string, but I have no idea how to do it as a return statement.

Any help to achieve the purpose of the assignment would be appreciated.

Comment: How does this even qualify as a string to palindrome conversion problem? Ideally, what you are trying to achieve here is: 1.Calculate the length of the string and divide it into 2 halves. 2, Take the first half and reverse it. 3 Concat the result with the first half.

Comment: But the thing is, that code doesn't work, and since another for loop is inside a for loop because I'm making a palindrome of the ELEMENTS of an array, it doesn't work and everything got messed up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be updated to this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

      public static String [] changeArrayToPalindrome(String [] arr){
          int length =arr.length;
          String[]newarray= new String[length];
          for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
             String a=arr[i];

             if(a==null){
                newarray[i]=null;
             }
             else if(a.equals("")){
              newarray[i]="";
             } else {
                 int n=a.length();
                 String newString="";
                 if (n%2==0) {
                     //for even
                     newString=a.substring(0,n/2); 
                 } else {
                     newString=a.substring(0,n/2+1);
                 }


                 for(int j=n/2-1; j>=0; j--){        
                    newString+=a.charAt(j);

                 }
                 newarray[i]=newString;
             }

          }
          return newarray;
      }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] array={"street", null, "break", "oha", "", "pit", null,"atOyotA"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(changeArrayToPalindrome(array)));

    }

}
```

Comment: you can use ```for loop``` instead of ```substring()``` if you are not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"abc", null, "abcdef"};
        List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(strings)
                .map(s -> s == null ? s : s.substring(0, (s.length() + 1) / 2) + reverseStringForPalin(s.substring(0, s.length() % 2 == 0 ? (s.length() + 1) / 2 : ((s.length() + 1) / 2) - 1)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(collect);
    }

    private static String reverseStringForPalin(String s) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
        return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
    }
```

In case you do not want to use `StringBuilder`:

```
private static String reverseStringForPalin(String s) {
        String reversed = "";
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversed += s.charAt(i);
        }
        return reversed;
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Basically what `map` does is take an object and transform it into another object. But if you do not want to use it, simply convert the `streams` to traditional `for`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"abc", null, "abcdef"};

        String[] output = new String[strings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
            if (strings[i] == null) {
                output[i] = null;
            } else {
                final String s = strings[i];
                output[i] = s.substring(0, (s.length() + 1) / 2) + reverseStringForPalin(s.substring(0, s.length() % 2 == 0 ? (s.length() + 1) / 2 : ((s.length() + 1) / 2) - 1));
            }
        }
```

And here is the code (directly from Java) for substring:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
        }
        if (endIndex > value.length) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
        }
        int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
        if (subLen < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
        }
        return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
                : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to use Array list and I don't know all those .map, s:substring or stuff like that. Would there be a way to solve it without using those? I'm a beginner to Java ^^;. Appreciated though :).